# Upgrading from 3.2.1 to current

Tags: upgrade

I had a Wordpress blog running on a server that suddenly disappeared on me.  I have backups of both the files & the database, but I was running v3.2.1.

I have access to a new server that runs the current version of WP.  Apparently v3.2.1 was running a (now) old version of PHP, such that can't really upgrade my Wordpress instance to the current instance.

Is there anyway I can get my v3.2.1 data into a current WP instance?  If it matters, I don't care about my themes.  I basically just want to get the posts back.